# Clean proof that the inverse metric tensor really is the inverse

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, tensor-calculus

In Frederic Schuller's lectures on GR, he [defines](https://youtu.be/ONCZNwKswn4?t=411) the metric tensor as a $(0,2)$-tensor field satisfying:

1. $g(X,Y)=g(Y,X) \,\,\,\forall X,Y$
2. $\flat (X)$ is a $C^\infty$-isomorphism, where $\flat(X):=g(X,\cdot)$

He then [defines](https://youtu.be/ONCZNwKswn4?t=868) the inverse metric tensor as the $(2,0)$-tensor field satisfying:

1. $g^{-1}(\omega,\sigma)=\omega(\flat^{-1}(\sigma))$

He then claims without proof that $(g^{-1})^{am}g_{mb}=\delta^a_b$.

**Can someone offer a clean proof of this statement, starting from Schuller's definitions?**

I began with this:

$$\begin{align} (g^{-1})^{am}g_{mb} &= g^{-1}(e^a,e^m)\cdot g(e_m,e_b) \\ &= e^a(\flat^{-1}(e^m))\cdot \flat(e_m)(e_b) \end{align}$$

If I could just massage this to leave $e^a(e_b)$ that would do it, but this seems tricky as the above is really a summation over $m$, and also the $e^a$ and $e_b$ are separated by a multiplication over $\mathbb{R}$, whereas we need the $e^a$ to "act on" the $e_b$. I also tried thinking in terms of matrix multiplication, but this gets messy and confusing since $\flat$ needs to act on column vectors but produce row vectors.

Comment: This is just a basic fact about bilinear forms by the way.  Not really appropriate for physics.SE

Comment: Well it pertains to foundational mathematics of GR—what are the tags "differential geometry" and "tensor calculus" doing in physics.SE if questions like this aren't intended for the site?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the quantity

$$ X^a{}_b = g^{-1}(e^a, \flat(e_b)) $$

Without using the definition of $g^{-1}$, this is equal to

$$(g^{-1})^{am}\flat(e_b)_m = (g^{-1})^{am} g(e_b, e_m) =  (g^{-1})^{am}g_{mb} $$

Using the definition of $g^{-1}$, we have

$$X^a{}_b = e^a(\flat^{-1}( \flat(e_b)))  = e^a(e_b)$$